# Why doesn't gpg need us to specify which keys for encryption and decryption?

Tags: gpg

The GNU Privacy Handbook says:

> The command-line option --sign is used to make a digital signature.
>   The document to sign is input, and the signed document is output.
>
> ```
> alice% gpg --output doc.sig --sign doc
>
> You need a passphrase to unlock the private key for
> user: "Alice (Judge) <alice@cyb.org>"
> 1024-bit DSA key, ID BB7576AC, created 1999-06-04
>
> Enter passphrase:
> ```

Why doesn't it ask  which private key to be used? Can't the user running the command hold multiple private keys?

> A document can be encrypted with a symmetric cipher by using the
>   --symmetric option.
>
> ```
> alice% gpg --output doc.gpg --symmetric doc
> Enter passphrase:
> ```

Does gpg use the passphrase to symmetrically encrypt the input file?
Or does it use the passphrase just to access the key which will be used to symmetrically encrypt the input file?
If latter, why does it not ask which key to be used for symmetric encryption? Can't the user hold multiple keys which can be used for symmetric encryption?

When decrypt a symmetrically encrypted file,

> ```
> alice% gpg --descrypt doc.gpg
> ```

will succeed. why does it not ask for passphrase (and the key to decrypt)? How can others then decrypt   `doc.gpg`  after I give it to them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GnuPG will use the *first* key found in the secret keyring if neither `--default-user` nor `--local-user` is specified.  You may also define the default key to be used with

```
default-key KEYID
```

in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.

Symmetric encryption does *not* involve any public or private keys.  The passphrase that you enter is used to both encrypt and decrypt the message (hence "symmetric").

In your example, you will not be asked for the passphrase when decrypting because the `gpg-agent` process has cached the passphrase that you used when encrypting the message.  If you terminated the agent and tried to decrypt the message again, you would be asked for the passphrase.

If you share your `doc.gpg` file and if it's encrypted with *symmetric* encryption, you would also need to share the passphrase somehow for enabling the recipients to decrypt the message. Anyone with the passphrase would be able to decrypt the message.

When using key encryption with signing, it would be enough to share you public key (for verification of the signature). Without signing, you don't have to share your key. Using key encryption, the message would be encrypted for one or several *specific* recipients, so you would need to have their public keys to perform the encryption. Without access to the *private* keys of the specific recipients, the message would not be able to be decrypted.

Comment: The relevant documentation is [here for `--default-key`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html) (which also explains how the key is chosen by default), and [here for symmetric encryption](https://gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html) (the paragraph which Tim quotes starts by saying “Documents may also be encrypted without using public-key cryptography.”).

Comment: `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye` to clear the gpg passphrase cache.

Comment: @Kusalananda - but how do I get the `KEYID`? In what format? When I do `gpg -K`, I get long ID with spaces.  What is the point of your answer, when you omit the most important thing.

Comment: @400theCat I don't get key IDs with spaces when I use `gpg2 -K`. I get key IDs in the format `rsa4096/HHHHHHHH` (where `H` is a hexadecimal digit). See also the `--key-format` option in the manual (this can be set with `keyid-format short` or `keyid-format long` etc. in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`).